# How can i fix [an error occurred while processing this directive]?

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch email from inbox using php imap(). In localhost function works fine but on our bluehost based dedicated server it showing following error

```
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

**Php Code**

```
$imap = @imap_open("{mail.******.com:143/novalidate-cert}", "a****i@*****.com", "******");

if(isset($imap)){
                $message_count = @imap_num_msg($imap);
                $array_mail = array();
                if($message_count > 0){
                    for ($m = 1; $m <= $message_count; ++$m){
                        //$header = @imap_header($imap, $m);
                        $header = @imap_rfc822_parse_headers(imap_fetchheader($imap, $m));
                        $email[$m]['from'] = $header->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$header->from[0]->host;
                        //$email[$m]['fromaddress'] = $header->from[0]->personal;
                        //$email[$m]['to'] = $header->to[0]->mailbox;
                        //$email[$m]['cc'] = $header->cc[0]->mailbox;
                        //$email[$m]['subject'] = $header->subject;
                        //$email[$m]['message_id'] = $header->message_id;
                        //$email[$m]['date'] = $header->udate;

                        //$from = $email[$m]['fromaddress'];
                        $from_email = $email[$m]['from'];
                        $array_mail[] = $from_email;
                        if(isset($header->cc)){
                            $hedCC = $header->cc;
                            foreach($hedCC as $s){
                                echo $s->mailbox.'@'.$s->host.'<br />';
                                //$array_mail[] = $s->mailbox.'@'.$s->host;
                            }
                        }

                        if(isset($header->to)){
                            $hedTO = $header->to;
                            foreach($hedTO as $t){
                                echo $t->mailbox.'@'.$t->host.'<br />';
                                //$array_mail[] = $t->mailbox.'@'.$t->host;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $i = 0;
                    if (!empty($array_mail)) {
                        $insertCount = 0;
                        foreach($array_mail as $m_){
                            // INSERT HERE
                            //echo $m_.'<br />';
                            $isExistWithID  = $this->isExistWithID($user_id,$m_);
                            $email_err      = $this->isValidEmail($m_);
                            $isValid = 0;
                            if($email_err == false){
                                $isValid = 1;
                            }
                            if($isExistWithID==0 && $isValid==0){
                                $insert = $this->pdoConnection->prepare("
                                    INSERT INTO ws_email (
                                        u_id,
                                        we_email, 
                                        date_added
                                    ) 
                                    VALUES(
                                        :u_id, 
                                        :we_email, 
                                        :date_added
                                    )
                                    ");
                                $insert->bindParam(':u_id', $u_id);
                                $insert->bindParam(':we_email', $we_email);
                                $insert->bindParam(':date_added', $date_added);

                                // Insert Data
                                $u_id           = $_SESSION['USERID'];
                                $we_email       = $m_;
                                $date_added     =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                                if($insert->execute()){
                                    $insertCount++;
                                }
                            }
                            $i++;

                        }// end foreach
                        $response['success']        = $insertCount . ' Email address(s) fetched successfully.';
                    } 
                    //echo $i; 
                    //
                }else{
                    $response['error']      = 'No record found';
                }
            }else{
                $response['error']      = 'IMAP does not connect'; 
            }
        /************ END NEW 29 SEP *************/
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Can anyone kindly guide me where is the issue that i can fix. I would like to appreciate. Thank You.

**EDITED**
I added ticket to host provider. Following are the comments,

```
This error is because of a the FCGI timeout. This can be fixed by changing to suphp. You can change the php type in the whm to suphp on the Main >> Service Configuration >> Apache Configuration >> PHP and SuExec Configuration page. I suggest to closely watch the website with that to suphp as it makes the server more vulnerable to scripts running unchecked.
```

Comment: what's the file extension for this? I've only seen this type of error when using `.shtml` file extensions or including a php file in a `.shtml` file, or vice-versa.

Comment: @Fred-ii- in the simple .php file

Comment: *Hm...*, most bizarre. Well, let's see if anyone else knows something I don't.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I received following comment from bluehost support `This error is because of a the FCGI timeout. This can be fixed by changing to suphp. You can change the php type in the whm to suphp on the Main >> Service Configuration >> Apache Configuration >> PHP and SuExec Configuration page. I suggest to closely watch the website with that to suphp as it makes the server more vulnerable to scripts running unchecked.`

Comment: Ah ok. TBH, I won't be of much help in that area, sorry. At least you have something to go on now, and maybe add that in your question, in case someone doesn't see it in comments, should they start to be more.